# What happens to Death Cloud when there aren't enough legal targets

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Probably a really easy one but if I play [Death Cloud](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death%20Cloud) where X=5 and my opponent only has 4 creatures does Death Cloud get countered because there aren't enough legal targets or does it just force him to sacrifice them all and ignore the last one?

Comment: Even though Death Cloud doesn't target, if it were a spell that did target, you couldn't even cast it in the first place if you didn't have enough targets. It wouldn't be countered for that reason. (It would be countered if its targets _become_ illegal while the spell is on the stack.) There's probably a question somewhere on this site about that, and it's also explained in the rules.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Death Cloud does not target. The only time a spell targets is when it says target on the spell (or a keyword on it uses target, eg Enchant X or Support N). Thus Death Cloud will do as much as it can and make them sacrifice all 4 of their creatures.

> **609.3.** If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.
>
> Example: If a player is holding only one card, an effect that reads “Discard two cards” causes him or her to discard only that card. If an effect moves cards out of the library (as opposed to drawing), it moves as many as possible.